# jquery - apply new instance to each instance of css class

Tags: jquery

Oh boy - this is going to be an easy one for you guys (unfortunately I am a newbie when it comes to JS). I really appreciate your help! Thank you!

Here's my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
var colors = ['#e5e5e5','#d3f2eb','#cce3ff', '#97d8c9', '#97e9c4', '#c9f9b2', '#c1d4d5', '#b2d5fd', '#fdebb2', '#5cc2ab', '#5cdca2', '#aaf587', '#9ebbbe', '#87bdfc', '#fce086'];
var random_color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
$('.bannercolor').css('background-color', random_color);
});

<div class="bannercolor">Div ONE</div>
<div class="bannercolor">Div TWO</div>
<div class="bannercolor">Div THREE</div>
```

The jquery applies the same background color to all three divs on my page. What I would like is for a different color to be chosen from my array for each div. Div One might be blue...div Two might be green etc.

Could you guys help me figure out how to modify my code to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a different class for each div if you want to set the color based on that class. Or, iterate over the elements in the class and assign the css to "this". You also need to get the color and set it for each div (i.e. three times).

Here's an example where we iterate over the elements in the class and assign a background color to each.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var colors = ['#e5e5e5', '#d3f2eb', '#cce3ff', '#97d8c9', '#97e9c4', '#c9f9b2', '#c1d4d5', '#b2d5fd', '#fdebb2', '#5cc2ab', '#5cdca2', '#aaf587', '#9ebbbe', '#87bdfc', '#fce086'];

  $('.bannercolor').each(function() {
    var random_color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    $(this).css('background-color', random_color);
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi Devlin, Thank you this code works really well! I was wondering if it would be possible to swap out background-color for background-image? Would you be able to help me out with that in exchange for a $20 contribution to your coffee fund ? :)

Comment: background-image: linear-gradient (rgba(204, 227, 255, 1), rgba(204, 227, 255, 1)); Looks like that. Whereas  background-color: rgb(252, 224, 134); renders like that. Notice that with background-image there is rgba and not rgb. Anyway I'm not sure if this is something possible and easy or not. If it's something simple that you know how to do, then like I said, i will PM you to get your paypal email or other info.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I needed. What's an email associated with a PayPal account you use? If you're in the United States and use Venmo I can do that too. Just let me know! Leah

Comment: My email LCDERUS@gmail.com